# How to debug `rails s` when it hangs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, output

I have strange problem. After running `rails s` on some project, the script hangs with no output and no logs. How can I debug it and inspect what's going on? I use rvm with ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: I may turns out that logging is simply disabled in app config.

Answer (score 1):

check `log/production.log`  to find the last file or line of code executed and try to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Probably `log/development.log` if `rails s` was started without specific enviroment variables being set.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dig a big deeper, you can use utilities such as "strace" or "dtruss" to see what files are being opened.

```
Linux:
$ strace rails s

Mac:
$ sudo dtruss rails s
```

You might not know what all of the output means, but you might get an idea if something is missing.